# java script code in html to consume webservices in java

Tags: javascript

I'm getting {error:please use post request}. Here is the code i tried:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btn").click(function (event) {
        var uid = document.getElementById("fpsid").value;
        var pwd = document.getElementById("Pass").value;
        var dataString = "{ 'fpsid' : '" + uid + "', 'Pass' : '" + pwd + "'}";

        $.ajax({
            ServiceCallID: 1,
            url: "http://epds.nic.in/PossWebService/services/Poss?wsdl",
            type: 'POST',
            data: dataString,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",

            success: function (result) {
                returnVal = result.d;
                alert(returnVal);
            },

            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                returnVal = '';
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Edit that into your post. That doesn't belong as a comment.

Comment: do you have a js fiddle?

Comment: What is `ServiceCallID` supposed to be?

Comment: var dataString... Thats not the way to create a json object

Answer (score 0):

To start, `dataString` is not [valid JSON](http://jsonlint.com/). [Object keys must be **double** quoted.](http://www.json.org/) To that end, there's a far better way of generating JSON given an object than string concatenation. Use [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify):

```
dataString = JSON.stringify({
    fpsid: uid,
    Pass: pwd
});
```

or just let jQuery worry about it:

```
var postData = {
    fpsid: uid,
    Pass: pwd
};

$.ajax({
    // ...
    data: postData,
    // ...
});
```